# There was an error connecting to Apple ID server

Tags: mac, icloud, apple-id, keychain

I am trying to login to iTunes App Store or the Mac App store on my Mac but it gives me the error every time "There was an error connecting to Apple ID server". Till now I have :

- Removed all the antivirus
- Disabled firewall
- Reset HOSTS file
- Tried all suggestions in [If you can’t connect to the iTunes Store - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201400)

I am on El Capitan 10.11.2 on a 2012 Mac Mini.

What I have not tried is Keychain first aid, which was ironically removed in this version of Mac OS. About the security content of OS X El Capitan 10.11.2, Security Update 2015-005 Yosemite, and Security Update 2015-008 M…

What should I do ?

Mac mini, OS X El Capitan (10.11.2)

Here is the log from Console:
http://pastebin.com/raw/8FTiHQF6

Comment: Try rebooting all your network hardware, then the Mac.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have done that already. All the other services on my Mac connect to the internet just fine. Everything that connects to Apple ID server does not.

Comment: A problem I run into a bit to often when someone complains about something not working, IS IT CONNECTED TO THE NETWORK?

Answer (score 1):

Old question: new answer.  Today I had the same problem on my iPad mini.  It turns out that a prior troubleshooting solution was to manually reset the date to an earlier time.  My date was 4 years (yes!) off.  I went to settings and changed to my iPad time to "set automatically" and everything worked.  Other symptoms besides this included the search function in the app store never returning any results.  That was also fixed once the correct time was set.

Answer (score -1):

Try going into Keychain and checking under Keychain Access --> Preferences --> Certificates to make sure both OCSP and CRL are "Best attempt".  See discussion here:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/29988458#29988458

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the linked page directly to your answer. Adding a reference is ok, but answers should stand on their own without having essential information hidden on another site.